# C++ kafka consumer group example

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka and to produce and consume messages from a topic with 3 partitions.
Currently I have 3 std::thread one for each partition.
I'm wondering if it is possible to use abstract this using something like Consumer Group.

Comment: See http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html